# async function as argument to setInterval nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, setinterval

When I pass an async function as argument to setInterval, it has a strange behaviour: it works a few times but then stops without any exception.

```js
setInterval(() => doSomethingAsync(), 1000);
```

I have no idea why.

I tried to implement my own setIntervalAsync but the behaviour is the same:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const setIntervalAsync = async (func, interval) => {
  while (true) {
    await func();
    await sleep(interval);
  }
};

// schedule it
setIntervalAsync(async () => await doSomethingAsync(), 1000);
```

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't understand why it stops. I want to make setInterval (or reproduce it) work with async functions

Comment: What's happening inside `doSomethingAsync()`?  I'm guessing that you're leaking some resource or something like that.  `setInterval()` just calls its function over and over again.  It doesn't care whether the function is a regular function or an `async` function or whether the function has an asynchronous operation in it or not.

Comment: @jfriend00 inside the func, it makes a call to amazon s3

Comment: And, this is in node.js?  Does your computer go to sleep?

Comment: What if `doSomethingAsync()` takes more than 1 seconds? How the code inside `doSomethingAsync` take in accoun that? It's possible that the overlaps of those calls makes your code "stops".

Comment: @jfriend00 yes this is nodejs v10.16.3. Why do you mean by go to sleep ?

Comment: When some computers are idle, they go to sleep (screen goes dark, CPU powers down) and they stop further processing until something wakes them up (to save energy).  Phones, laptops, tablets and some desktops all do that.

Comment: What happens if `doSomethingAsnc()` is called the 2nd time before the 1st one has finished.  Do they interfere with each other?

Comment: @jfriend00 No it doesn't sleep. And ```doSomethingAsync()``` isn't called a second before the first call finishes because as you can see in my custome function ```setIntervalAsync```, I wait for the resolution before looping again

Comment: In your `setIntervalAsync()`, if your `func()` throws or rejects, your loop will  stop and you don't seem to log or handle errors anywhere.

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but , `setIntervalAsync(async () => await doSomethingAsync(), 1000);`, can just be `setIntervalAsync(doSomethingAsync, 1000);`.  No need for the extra function or the extra `await`.  You're already awaiting the function inside your `setItnervalAsync()`.

Comment: @jfriend00 my ```func()``` doesn't throw anything, the entire function is wrapped by a try catch

Comment: Is the callback synchronous or asynchronous?  Does it return a promise?  Does it free/release all possible resources that it uses.  We're blind here with no relevant code.  The operative code is that callback code.  99% chance, that's where the problem is.  `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` don't just stop on their own.  I don't think there's anything we can do to help you here without seeing the actual code you're calling.

Comment: As a test, try running this `let cntr = 1; setIntervalAsync(() => { console.log("still running", cntr++)}, 1000);` and see if that runs indefinitely.  If it does, then the problem is inside the code you're not sharing with us.

Comment: @jfriend00 doing this ```setIntervalAsync(doSomethingAsync, 1000);``` doesn't run the func once... With your example, it does run indefinitely indeed. The problem must be in the callback. I will look at it tomorrow, thanks for your time

Comment: If `setIntervalAsync(doSomethingAsync, 1000);` doesn't even run your function once, then there's something seriously wrong in your function.  As you can see in the implementation of `setIntervalAsync()`, the first material thing it does is call `await fn()` where `fn` is `doSomethingAsync`.  So, I don't see how it wouldn't call `doSomethingAsync` at least once.  There is definitely something screwy going on in that function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202781/discussion-between-newlol-and-jfriend00).

Comment: @jfriend00 the problem was completly different than I expected. It was not in the callback, nor in setInterval. It was working perfectly from the beginning. Due to a bug in my logger (the syslog tag changed) I wasn't able to see the new logs coming. That was pretty stupid, thanks for your time

Comment: so weird you would set an interval and and run an asynchronous task and want both to be synchronous.... Sounds like your task would be better accomplished with a different pattern. What is your actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @epascarello What do you mean by "want both to be synchronous" ? All I'm doing is regularly executing an asynchronous function (a call to s3). But it is working, the problem was something else, see my previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was elsewhere and completly unrelated to setInterval or my callback.

setInterval is working fine with async functions.

Comment: Probably best to just delete this answer and your question since there's no helpful info about what was the real problem in the question or answer and thus this is of no help to anyone as a long term reference.  Glad you figured it out though.  In all my years of programming, the hardest problems to solve are the ones where you somehow get a wrong assumption about the problem.  That's certainly what got you here.